# How to swap json

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, swap

In my angular code on page load there are list of buttons like button 1, button 2, button 3.. etc on click of every button it shows J-SON on console the structure is same for all buttons but the values vary. There are two more buttons on page on up and down.

My question is if  button 2  is selected and i click on up button then the position of  button 2  should moved up to  button 1  for that we have use one attribute in  j-son  but problem m facing is that how should i swap whole  j-son  like how to swap position of  button 2  to  button 1  and vice-versa for down arrow

searched for swapping on google but it showing items in array to swap. i want whole  j-son  to swap

```
up(){ 
  exchange(this.jsondata,up,up+1); 
} 

private exchange(array: any, x: any, y: any) { 
  const temp = array[x]; 
  array[x] = array[y]; 
  array[y] = temp; 
  return array; 
}
```

it should change the position of buttons on click of up down buttons

Comment: show some code that you have tried

Comment: code is `
    up(){
exchange(up,up+1);
} 

private exchange(Array: any, x: any, y: any) {
    const temp = Array[x];
    Array[x] = Array[y];
    Array[y] = temp;
    return Array;

  }
'

Comment: This is just an opinion (hence not an answer), but I don't think you should be re-ordering the JSON itself. JSON is just raw data; it shouldn't matter what order it is in. You really should be ordering the data arrays/objects in your code and let the JSON be whatever it is.

Comment: By the way, are you referring to actual JSON or JavaScript arrays/objects? They are not the same.

Comment: `i want whole j-son to swap` ← This statement is very unclear. Please [edit] your question and add exactly what it is you are wanting to do. Provide an [mcve] with the current result and add the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is swapping two elements in an array, your exchange function seems ok.

But you are calling it with only 2 parameters : `up(up, up+1)` while your function takes 3 parameters :

- the array where the items are
- the first item
- the second item

If your buttons were in an array named `myButtons`, you would probably want to call it that way :

`up(myButtons, up, up+1);`

Side notes :

- be careful what you're naming your parameters. [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array) is a global JavaScript object. It's not a good practice to use that name for a variable.
- `up` is obviously the name of a function and a variable. That is kind of confusing.
- your function returns the array that was passed as a paramter. That is not necessary since arrays are passed as references. You can make your function immutable and have it return a different array. Or modify the reference and not return anything.

Comment: i want to swap buttons and i am consoling that on every click of button it shows json so if i want change the position of two buttons how can i do?

Comment: You should probably paste more code than that for us to help you. Including your template.